# set html dir attribute based on locale

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

Setting i18n-locale in angular.json's build config to an RTL language like Hebrew, does not change html's dir attribute to RTL. Is there another way to automatically set html or body `dir` attribute based on locale?

Answer (score 1):

AppComponent should listen to language change as following:

app.component.ts

```cpp
@Component(...)
export class AppComponent {

  public dir: string;
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.onLangChange.subscribe(x => this.dir = x == "en" ? "ltr" : "rtl")
  }

}
```

app.component.html:

```html
<div [dir]="dir">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```